# Remote iframe issues in Metro application

Tags: iframe, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I've seen this SO posting about using iframe's and doing postMessage: [Metro App and iFrame cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901272/metro-app-and-iframe-cookie). I'm trying to do something very similar in Win8 Release Preview with an HTML/JS Metro application, but it seems rather impossible to replicate the behavior in that solution.

I have a simple frame stored in a remote location as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
window.onmessage = function(e) {
    alert("Hello world");

    debugger;
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my default.html I have a div that contains the iframe as follows:

```
<div id="container">
    <iframe id="frame" src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/75275447/win8Frame.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

I have an arbitrary button that executes a postMessage on #frame and would in a normal Html site trigger the remote frames onmessage, but instead I can look at the error list in VS and see:

> APPHOST9613: The app couldn’t navigate to
>   https://dl.dropbox.com/u/75275447/win8Frame.html because of this
>   error: RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND.

I have tried looking into any manifest that might allow me to achieve this and enabled:

- Home or Work Networking
- Internet (Client & Server)
- Internet (Client)

To no avail... I have also tried having a frame (local to the application) loaded into the web contenxt (via ms-wwa-web://) that contains a div that hosts the remote iframe and chain up onmessage to forward a postMessage to the remote iframe, but again I see another error:

> APPHOST9624: The app can’t use script to load the
>   ms-wwa-web://frame.html/ url because the url launches another app.
>   Only direct user interaction can launch another app.

I'm beginning to think this is an impossible task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one piece of information I leave out as I considered it unrelated to this issue was an error found in the **javascript console** related to using Jquery that I found a solution in another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859523/using-jquery-with-windows-8-metro-javascript-app-causes-security-error).  Clearing up that issue now allows the app to load the remote iframe and I can press the button and see the message reach the remote iframe's javascript (in my case I see alert() being undefined, but I was just trying to prove that I could load and execute remote code).

I guess the moral of the story is clear up related **javascript console** errors...